# How do you test req.flash() in express?

Tags: node.js, tdd, express

I currently have an express/node application I want to test, and but responses that it gives are in the form of `req.flash('warn', 'message goes here');`

Unfortunately, the documentation on [express.js](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) does not describe how this message travels to the client very thoroughly.

I know [expresso](http://visionmedia.github.com/expresso/) has an assert.response() function that tests response objects. I was wondering where the flash message goes, and how I can test it in a similar way (or if it's not possible, and I should be sending everything through the response object).

Comment: Does looking at the source help? https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash

Answer (score 12):

i don't think this is supposed to work like that. you can't just use `req.flash()`as your only way to respond to a request.

it's more like an easy way to flash messages to the user on your `normal` templates - e.g. after inserting/creating an article you can either say:

```
req.flash('error', 'could not insert because .... ');
```

or

```
req.flash('info', 'article added successfully!');
```

for my last project i then added two dynamic helpers to my app:

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
    info: function (req, res) {
        return req.flash('info');
    },
    error: function (req, res) {
        return req.flash('error');
    }
});
```

so that i can just say sth like this in my view:

```
<% if (info !== undefined && info != "") { %>
<div class="infoBubble"> 
    <%= info %>
</div>
<% } %>

<% if (error !== undefined && error != "") { %>
<div class="errorBubble"> 
    <strong>Fehler</strong>: <%= error %>
</div>
<% } %>
```

result looks like this:

[image: screenshot of flash bubble]

Comment: Nice, I like those helpers - ty.